# Can I use the UITableView grouped background pattern for a UIView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uikit

I like the default background of a grouped `UITableView`.  I'd like to use it on a standard `UIView`.

I'm unable to find anyone asking this question or any reference how to accomplish it.

Any recommendations on how to do this? Is it even possible outside of creating and image and loading that as the background?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the GroupedTableViewBackgroundColor in Interface Builder or

```
backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

Comment: groupTableViewBackgroundColor has beed deprecated since iOS 6. Make an empty grouped tableView and place it behind the tableview. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6